# How to find type of the field with specific name in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Need to find `TypeSyntax` or essentially `Type` of a specific filed in class by using Roslyn.
Something like this:

```
rootSyntaxNode
.DescendantNodes()
.OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>()
.First(x => x.Identifier="fieldName")
.GivemeTypeSyntax()
```

But could not get any hint about how to reach Identifier and SyntaxType in FieldDeclarationSyntax node. Any idea please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the issue is that fields can contain multiple variables. You'll look at `Declaration` for type and `Variables` for identifiers. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
class MyClass
{
    int firstVariable, secondVariable;
    string thirdVariable;
}");

var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { mscorlib });

var fields = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>();

//Get a particular variable in a field
var second = fields.SelectMany(n => n.Declaration.Variables).Where(n => n.Identifier.ValueText == "secondVariable").Single();
//Get the type of both of the first two fields.
var type = fields.First().Declaration.Type;
//Get the third variable
var third = fields.SelectMany(n => n.Declaration.Variables).Where(n => n.Identifier.ValueText == "thirdVariable").Single();
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused by what a "field" is, but wouldn't that be 3 fields and 3 variables?  Is mean isn't `int first, second;` just a short-hand synonym for `int first; int second;` or am I missing something?

Comment: Similar to above question, How can a field have more than one variable?

Comment: I think I answered my own question: From microsoft docs: "You can declare multiple variables of the same type in one statement"  So sounds like in the above, `firstVariable` and `secondVariable` are a single declaration, with two variables. So you need to loop over the variables get them both.